# Стриминг RTMP потока в Android

Tags: streaming, android, видео

Здравствуйте , нужно проигрывать онлайн видео с веб камеры без использования WebView. Основная ссылка с видео [Страница с видео](http://about.osnova.tv/webcams/8). С помощью программы URL Helper получил ссылку RTMP потока вот

> `rtmp://193.151.107.242<playpath>cam_plosch
> <swfUrl>http://about.osnova.tv/player/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf
> <pageUrl>http://about.osnova.tv/webcams/8`

. Подскажите пожалуйста как проиграть видео с данного потока. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/ Вот сторонняя китайская библиотека.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вы не подскажете где можно хотя бы пример использования библиотеки этой найти. Документации тоже не смогу найти на сайте .

Comment: У них же в исходниках там пример. https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexample%2Fcom%2Fryong21%2Fexample